# What is the mechanism by which an animal has behavioral instincts?

Tags: evolution, instinct

I understand (at a layman's level) how evolution and natural selection work in regards to anatomy.  The offspring has a slight mutation that makes it a better survivor in some way -- faster, stronger, more agile, better camouflage, more efficient respiration, whatever.

But I have no idea how instinctual behavior is developed and/or transferred.

Observing my house cats, I can see that they have all kids of instincts for hunting, fighting, playing, grooming, etc etc.

Where did these instincts come from?  Animals (including humans) are born already knowing a lot of things, right?  That's what "instinct" means.

How does that work?  Do we even know?

Comment: Instincts are formed the same way anatomical attributes do: genetically. The nervous system has developed instincts (or reflexes, if it helps you to understand them better) through millions of years of selection; those individuals with beneficial instincts had a better chance of survival to reproductive age.

Comment: @anongoodnurse So instincts are also anatomical differences, localized in the nervous system?  And organisms with "bad instincts" died out?

Comment: I believe so, yes. [Instincts](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5182125/) can mean different things to different people, so there's room for debate. They can be said to be genetically coded for neurologically, though they can also be altered by the environment. A neuroscientist might argue that there is no one satisfactory explanation for instincts, but that we are born with many of them is irrefutable. Dogs bred over time to hunt and kill small animals (e.g. vermin) will have a very high prey drive whereas those bred solely for companionship may have a very low prey drive.

Comment: This site has a policy of the OP showing evidence of research (e.g. links to an article and a quote) in an attempt to answer the question; if you [edit] your post to include some, you may get a much better answer than mine. I think it's a very interesting question.